# Matching specific strings, ignoring others

Tags: python, pyparsing

How do i match only certain strings using pyparsing? For example, i want to match only

```
OneOrMore(Word("Apple")|Word("Ball"))
```

but if the string is

```
"Apple Ball Cat"
```

then I want to ignore the `Cat` and get back

```
['Apple', 'Ball']
```

I can do this with regex but I want to know how it is done with pyparsing.

EDIT: `"Apple Cat Ball"` should also give `['Apple', 'Ball']`

I have tried

```
correct = Word("Apple")|Word("Ball")
pattern = OneOrMore(~vulnTypes.suppress() + vulnTypes)
result = pattern.parseString(string)
```

Comment: Yes i know about the re module but im wondering how to do this with pyparsing commands

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: Do you know all the words you want to skip? Or is it just "anything that is not in this set of known words"?

Comment: Yep, anything that is not in the set

Comment: Please read up on the differences between Word, Literal, and Keyword classes. I'm pretty sure Word is not the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, `Word` is not really the class to use for matching specific words - it *will* work, but it will also accept a lot of other words too. The reason is that `Word` takes a string containing the characters allowed in the current expression and will match any word group containing one or more of any characters in that string. For instance, you could parse any integer with `Word("0123456789")`. `Word("Apple")` will certainly match "Apple", but it will also match "AAAA", "pplplpelplepl", and another word made up of the characters "A", "p", "l", and "e". In this case, I think you are best served using `Keyword`.

It is best to start with some sample strings:

```
samples = """\
    Apple
    Apple Ball
    Ball Apple
    Apple Cat
    Apple Cat Ball Daisy Ball"""

APPLE = Keyword("Apple")
BALL = Keyword("Ball")
```

Since you know you want "Apple" and "Ball", but there may be others mixed in, then you could try defining an expression for "anything else". Now `Word` can make sense to use, because we want to match any word-group containing any non-space characters (using pyparsing's `printables` string).

```
anything_else = Word(printables)
```

Since you want these other words to be suppressed from the parsed output, we add the `.suppress()` call when creating this catch-all expression.

```
anything_else = Word(printables).suppress()
```

Now this will match *any* group of non-whitespace characters, including "Apple" and "Ball". To avoid accidentally dropping one of our desired words, we use the '|' operator (as you did in your original post), and make sure that `anything_else` is listed *last*. That is, all the other options will be tested first, and we will only reach the `anything_else` catch-all if we didn't match any of them.

Now your scanner expression can read:

```
pattern = OneOrMore(APPLE | BALL | anything_else)
```

And run it against your samples using:

```
pattern.runTests(samples)
```

and you should get back only the Apples and Balls in your output.

(Note that `Keyword` is case-sensitive. If you also want to match on "apple" and "ball" or "APPLE" or "BALL", then use `CaselessKeyword`.)